How can I correct a scope voltage reading?
I have a pocket scope that I'm using to help me learn to fix and make electronic things.  It's the DS211 single probe.
I understand this is a low end scope, but it generally does the job that I need.  The problem I'm having is that the voltage is off by about .2 on a 12V reading.  The probe has no adjustment and I fried the ground strap, so I'm using a jumper wire for the ground.
The resistance of the probe ground is 0.60
Q1. What difference does the resistance of the probe ground make?
Q2. Would an adjustable probe be able to correct the voltage reading or is there any other way to correct the readings?  It seems like about 2% off, which doesn't sound like a lot, but it is when most DMM are 0.5%

How do you know that its the oscilloscope that measures incorrectly by 200 mV?

A scope was never meant to make very accurate voltage readings so 2% is very typical accuracy even for high end scopes. In general, probes do not have an amplitude adjustment only a compensation adjustment for matching the probe to the scope input. There might be an internal adjustment for gain in the scope but this would require dismantling the scope and is not recommended unless the manual contains instructions. The resistance of the ground wire will not affect voltage measurements to any significant extent.

Q1. What difference does the resistance of the probe ground make?
At the low frequencies of such a 'scope product: none.
The 'scope input resistance is usually megohms, so the 'scope input current is, microamps at 12 V. Therefore the voltage drop in the 0.6 ohm wire is microvolts and negligible.

Q2. Would an adjustable probe be able to correct the voltage reading or is there any other way to correct the readings?
If the voltage reading is high, you could add a series resistance as the top resistor of a potential divider with the scope's internal input resistance acting as the bottom resistor. The scope's input resistance should be specified and is typically 1 MOhm.
That will reduce the scope's accuracy at higher frequencies. That might not matter if you're only measuring up to, say, 20 kHz as with audio. You can experiment with your particular 'scope. Start with a 100 kOhm series resistor and go from there.
